# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099

Tags: swift, inmobi

Can anyone of you please explain to me what this error is, and how this can be fixed. I have a swift app available in app store, i am trying to Monetize it by adding advertisements. I tried reaching out to the support team of the add platform, but no reply from their end. Below is the display i get in console. I would like to know what this means. I do see few comments in the board, to run a command in terminal, i did not try it yet... would like to know more about this error before i suppress the logs using the command. Thanks in advance.

I am trying to use INMOBI in my app for advertisements:

`2020-01-19 23:18:26.769190-0500 testadv[4386:92650] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated."` `UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2020-01-19 23:18:26.769421-0500 testadv[4386:92650] [Client] Updating selectors after delegate addition failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}`

Comment: did you check this https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK/issues/560 ?

Comment: Not yet... by any chance do u have the Swift/Obj C equivalent for this this issue.... the link refers to Cordova.

Answer (score -7):

Please write below command in you terminal as I have same issue and it was resolved with same command!

```
xcrun simctl spawn booted log config 
--mode "level:off"  
--subsystem com.apple.CoreTelephony
```

Comment: i came across this command in this forum, i believe this command just turns off the logging the error in console... i will Definitely try this, but would like to know what this is error is first, before logging it off.. might be if, i can fix it issue/warning it would be great....